# URL issue in NopCommerce dot(.) is not accept in URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm working on NopCommerce Project and
I want a URL like : *www.youstore.com/category.cfd*
but in SEO I entered the **category.cfd** but it does not accept the dot(.) in URL it will automatically remove dot(.) while i'm saving the SEO name.

Please, help me out for that

Comment: I need the dot in url just like :
www.youstore.com/category.cfd

Answer (score 2):

Dots in this kind of urls are not supported by nopcommerce, all the urls of products and categories are cleaned to keep seo friendly urls.

You can tweak nopcommerce to allow dots (changing the source code or changing the UrlRecord table values) but when you add a dot to the url, the .Net extensionless handler used to process mvc request will not catch that request anymore, that means that you will recieve a 404 error because the web server will be searching for a phisycal file.

If the dot is mandatory by your requirements you can use the **[url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)** at iis level and rewrite all the urls (for example all the urls finished with .cfd) removing the dot, so internally you will have www.youstore.com/categorycfd or www.youstore.com/category, this can be tricky because you need to keep dots for file paths as images.